# Unable to find hprof-conv when launching Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using the Android Studio IDE and the SDK that comes with it.
When trying to open the Android Device Monitor I continue to recieve a dialog box asking me to point to the Android SDK. When I do it suggests that it can't find the file tools/hprof-conv.

This worked a couple days ago and just started...even with fresh installs of android studio.
Here is a screen shot:
[image: Device Monitor Dialog]

Comment: **`hprof-conv`** apparently [moved to `platform-tools/`](https://twitter.com/droidxav/status/482568208289771520)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

FYI this should already be fixed with latest.

If you're seeing this error, re-run your Android SDK manager and make sure `Android SDK Tools` is updated to Rev. **23.0.1** or later.

Comment: This is such a gross oversight!  I want my money back!

Answer (score 69):

In the last versions of the SDK the hprof-conv.exe file is located at /platform-tools folder, not /tools. To fix this problem you should copy the hprof-conv.exe from the /platform-tools to /tools.

or for Linux you can navigate to the `tools` folder & use this command to make a link

```
ln -s ../platform-tools/hprof-conv hprof-conv
```

Comment: Thanks what I actually did was add both the tools and platform- tools folders to the system path variable.

Comment: People using UNIX can also navigate (using `cd`) to sdk/tools directory and then execute `ln -s ../platform-tools/hprof-conv hprof-conv`. This creates a link to the file rather than copy it.

Comment: @Pius Actually that was the first thing I tried but it didn't work. Mac OSX.

Comment: Linking works fine; just resolved this issue using that command. Also using OS X. Note that I had to delete and re-enter a character in the popup window to get it to recheck the directory for the binary.