# Android Device Monitor - Provide Path to Android SDK

Tags: android

I run Android Device Monitor yesterday, no problem. I start Android Studio today and it asks for updates. I update and restart Android Studio. Then I go to Android Device Monitor and it asks for path: [image]

And I still can't seem to find the path.

Comment: You have to specify the sdk path. Hope this will help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path

Comment: Just Update `Android SDK Tools` to 23.0.2
[repeated question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459037/unable-to-find-hprof-conv-when-launching-android-device-monitor

Answer (score 2):

You should copy the hprof-conv.exe from the /platform-tools to /tools and the problem will fix.